# Radio button keeps re-rendering when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, radio-button

I'm fetching data from an API, and I map over it in order to generate 5 groups of radio buttons. Everything works fine, except for the fact that when I click on any of the input radio buttons, it seems to re-render the entire component or something, as you can see below (this is only one of the groups, but it happens and affects all of them):

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function Question({ data }) {
    const [userSelections, setUserSelections] = useState({
        question0: "",
        question1: "",
        question2: "",
        question3: "",
        question4: "",
    })

    function handleSelection(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target

        setUserSelections(prevSelection => {
            return {
                ...prevSelection,
                [name]: value
            }
        })
    }

    const renderQuestionBlocks = data.map(({question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers, uniqueQuestionId}, questionIndex) => {
        const allAnswers = [...incorrect_answers, correct_answer].sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random())
        data.uniqueQuestionId = nanoid()

        return (
            <form className={`question--container question${questionIndex}`} key={data.uniqueQuestionId}>
                <p>{question.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&#039;/g, "'")}</p>
                
                {allAnswers.map((answer, answerIndex) => {
                    data[questionIndex].uniqueAnswerId = nanoid()
                    
                    return (
                    <div 
                        key={data[questionIndex].uniqueAnswerId}
                        className={`choice--container question${questionIndex}`}
                    >
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            name={`question${questionIndex}`}
                            id={`question${questionIndex}option${answerIndex}`}
                            value={answer}
                            checked={userSelections[`question${questionIndex}`] === answer}
                            onChange={handleSelection}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor={`question${questionIndex}option${answerIndex}`}>{answer.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&#039;/g, "'")}</label>
                    </div>
                    )
                })}             
            </form>
        )
    })
    
    return (
        <div className="questions--container">
            {renderQuestionBlocks}
            <button>Check answers</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems to re-render the entire component or something

Updating state re-renders a component.  This is expected and correct (and fundamentally necessary) behavior in React.  But... What does your component do when it renders?

It randomly sorts the values:

```
const allAnswers = [...incorrect_answers, correct_answer].sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random())
```

It sounds like either that sort shouldn't be random, or should be randomized outside the scope of this component, *or* that randomization should itself be persisted in state so you can re-use it on each render.

For example, if you just need *a* random number for the component then you can generate one and keep it in state:

```
const [randonNumber] = useState(Math.random());
```

This will randomly generate a number, but won't *re-generate* one on every render.  Then you can consistently use the same randomly generated number:

```
const allAnswers = [...incorrect_answers, correct_answer].sort((a, b) => 0.5 - randonNumber)
```

Comment: Omg thank you!!!! I'm new to React and am still getting used to the renders/order of renders and stuff. Your suggestion worked perfectly!